# Multiple API calls simultaniously in PHP

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, php-curl, curl-multi

I'm trying to request multiple APIs as fast as possible. So i've tried `curl_multi`. But I get slower results than with foreach and `file_get_contents`. What am I doing wrong?

With `file_get_contents`:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
$urls = array("https://www.example1.com/", "https://www.example2.com/", "https://www.example3.com/");

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $result = file_get_contents($url);
}

echo microtime(true) - $start;
?>
```

With `curl_multi`:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
$urls = array("https://www.example1.com/", "https://www.example2.com/", "https://www.example3.com/");
$urls_count = count($urls);
$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $urls_count; $i++)
{
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($urls[$i]);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}

do {
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
} while($running > 0);

for($i = 1; $i < $urls_count; $i++)
{
    $results = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
}

echo microtime(true) - $start;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that `curl_multi` has a lot of overhead. I am assuming that it would have to create a shell process for each request and then execute curl in that process and then finally return the contents to the script requesting the action. [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is optimized and inherent to the PHP language:

> file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

This is a good learning experience of when to use a library vs native functionality in a language. Also there might be an option for the library to be multithreaded and take advantage of multi-core processors which  might speed up the requests. Something to look up and test for yourself.